# How to remove header of gridview column in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, datagrid

I have a ListView with GridView content as below. I just add the delete and edit button to the end of each row. So i don't need the header for those columns. I collopsed the headers for those columns, this removes the headers but the place of the header of the columns looks like white as below. How to set the style for those columns as the header bar style ?

```
<Style x:Key="sahin" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
            </Style>
    
        <ListView Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding deckList}" >
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SurName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn  HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource sahin}" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button  Style="{StaticResource noBackgroundStyle}">
                                        <Image Source="/KillCard;component/Resources/Images/delete.png" Width="16"></Image>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource sahin}">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button  Style="{StaticResource noBackgroundStyle}">
                                        <Image Source="/KillCard;component/Resources/Images/edit.png" Width="16"></Image>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

[image: ListView]

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet shown below helped me.

```
<Style x:Key="sahin" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```